# Weird Javascript behavior that involves counters

Tags: javascript, css

I call the function

```
animate(0,"mainNav",0.02,0.04);
```

And the declaration

```
function animate(num, element, transitionUnit, delayUnit) {
    var delay = 0;
        transition = 0;
    //var delayUnit = 0.02; transitionUnit = 0.04;
    var x = document.getElementById(element).getElementsByTagName("LI");

    for (i = 0; i <= x.length - 1; i++) {
        x[i].style.WebkitTransform = "translate3d(" + num + "px,0,0)";
        x[i].style.transition = transition + "s " + delay + "s ease-in-out";
        delay += delayUnit;
        transition += transitionUnit;
        if (x[i].querySelectorAll('ul li').length > 0) {
            x[i].style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.35)";
        }
    }
}
```

If I uncomment...

```
//var delayUnit = 0.02; transitionUnit = 0.04;
```

...It works flawlessly.

But I want to use it with other functions that send different delayUnits and transitionUnits. Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens exactly when you use the parameters and not that commented-out line? Do you get errors?

Comment: Also, exactly how are you calling this? What happens if you replace that commented-out line with `delayUnit = +delayUnit; transitionUnit = +transitionUnit;` ?

Comment: i think you just inverted the two values :   `animate(0,"mainNav",0.02,0.04);` should be  `animate(0,"mainNav",0.04,0.02);`

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly declare all the variables:

```
function animate(num, element, transitionUnit, delayUnit) {
    var delay = 0;
    var transition = 0;
    var x = document.getElementById(element).getElementsByTagName("LI");

    for (var i = 0; i <= x.length - 1; i++) {
        x[i].style.WebkitTransform = "translate3d(" + num + "px,0,0)";
        x[i].style.transition = transition + "s " + delay + "s ease-in-out";
        delay += delayUnit;
        transition += transitionUnit;
        if (x[i].querySelectorAll('ul li').length > 0) {
            x[i].style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.35)";
        }
    }
}
```

Using implicit globals in for loops causes problems.

As aSeptik mentioned, you might be inverting values:

```
animate(0,"mainNav",0.04,0.02);
```

Comment: I figured it out. I put the calling function' parameters in quotes. It works. I don't know why.